# C# ternary operator. Don't understand one moment

Tags: c#

Why after the variable result becomes zero it again increases by 1 to 5 each time?

```
        for (int i = 5; i >= -5; i--)
        {
            result = i >= 0 ? i : -i;
            Console.Write("{0}\t", result);
        }
```

Output:

```
5       4       3       2       1       0       1       2       3       4     5
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWy2Y.jpg

Comment: What are you expecting it to output instead?

Comment: When 'i' is a negative number ie. Less than 0. You set result to negative 'i' and the negative of a negative is a positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop below has i as [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, **-1, -2, -3, -4, -5**].

```
   for (int i = 5; i >= -5; i--)
```

This line:

```
   result = i >= 0 ? i : -i;
```

Says:

> If i is greater than or equal to 0 then put i into the result. Otherwise put i * -1 into the result.

For values less than 0, -1 * that value gives you a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

While `i` is *above* 0 it prints out `i` (which is, of course, still positive). When `i` switches to *less* than 0 it prints out **negative** `i`.

A negative of a negative is a positive (ie, -1 * -1 = 1) so positive numbers are still printed.

Answer (score 0):

The Ternary Operator **?** works like a if else statement, in this case when your loop is false
(i<0) the first value of i is going to be -1 but your else statement declare: return -1 so: -1*-1 = 1.

**Remember**

```
                      **Ternary operator (?) structure**

                         (condition)  ?  1  :  0;
                         If condition is true (?) 1 : (Else) 0;
```

Comment: but where exactly multiplication is going ? оО
debug tools in VS is hiding this info from me =\
or should I accept what is happening and not otherwise?

Comment: a better way to read into this is: When You run the program the first value <0 is -1 so, this value enter in else statement code and add a -(value): --1 is simplification of terms.